# Customer Marketing Cloud unsubscribe process, do we need to handle complaints, bounces etc

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, unsubscribe

I am building a custom unsubscribe process. We make use of the connector. Everything works fine, but I'm wondering if we need to take care of _Complaints, _Bounces and _Unsubscribes. These are held during a send (right?), but are they also deleted in SalesCloud if we use the connector? Or will they be kept?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to take care of them. Nothing is deleted from Sales Cloud - you would have to create a process for this. The only things "visible" in Sales Cloud, would be the status of the email send in  [Individual Email Results](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_si_individual_recipient_tracking_data.htm&type=5) and the `EmailOptOut` flag on a Contact/Lead (if you're using it).

Also, nothing is deleted in Marketing Cloud - here is how this works on a high level:

**Unsubscribers**

When a subscriber unsubscribes, they are not removed from a list or account. Their status is changed to Unsubscribed, and a red icon appears next to their name on the list.

A subscriber can unsubscribe in three different ways:

- List Unsubscribe: A list unsubscribe occurs when a user unsubscribes from a list only.
- Master Unsubscribe: A master unsubscribe occurs when a subscriber unsubscribes from every email sent by your company.
- Global Unsubscribe: A global unsubscribe occurs when a subscriber chooses to unsubscribe from every email sent from Marketing Cloud.

Depending on how you set up your unsubscribe process in Marketing Cloud, if someone unsubscribes, they will be held for a single list or all emails.

If you're using the `EmailOptOut` flag that comes with Marketing Cloud Connector, a Master/Global unsubscribe will check that flag on a Contact/Lead in Sales Cloud.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_unsubscribes.htm&type=5

**Bounces**

A subscriber can bounce within the limits of bounce logic (3 times in 15+ days or 1 hard bounce from a trusted domain) and be classified with a held status. This means the subscriber status will remain in held status and will be suppressed from all future sends.

Note, that if an email address bounces and you update it to a new one in Sales Cloud, it will not be automatically updated in Marketing Cloud - you need to build a separate process for that.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340076&type=1&mode=1

Synching email address updates: https://markus.codes/2019/10/09/reactivate-subscribers-after-email-change-update-of-sync-email-changes-from-sfdc-to-marketing-cloud

**Complaints**

Complaints against messages lodged at ISPs with feedback loops will pass back into Marketing Cloud as unsubscribe requests.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314913&type=1&mode=1